# How to make this table better looking?

Tags: tables

I can't come up with an idea to make this table better looking. It appears rather dull. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\date{10 dicembre 2015}

 \maketitle

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
     Length target area (mm) & 220\\
    \hline 
     Width target area (mm) & 120\\
    \hline
     Length upper surface (mm) & 230\\
    \hline
     Width lower surface (mm) & 180\\
    \hline
     Length inconel foil (mm) & 250\\
    \hline
     Width inconel foil (mm) & 125\\
    \hline
     Conductivity inconel (W/mK) & 14.8\\
    \hline
     Conductivity duct tape (W/mK) & 0.2\\
    \hline
     Conductivity steel (W/mK) & 51.9\\
    \hline
     Thickness inconel (mm) & 0.0254\\
    \hline
     Thickness duct tape (mm) & 0.18\\
    \hline
     Thickness steel (mm) & 0.3\\
    \hline
     $\varepsilon_{steel}$ & 0.3\\
    \hline
    $\varepsilon_{int}$ & 0.25\\
   \hline
    $\varepsilon_{amb}$ & 1\\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Dimensioni del banco}
  \label{tab:dimensioni_banco}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ideas:

1. Don't use vertical rules
2. Split the unit column
3. The left column should be left aligned
4. The figures should either be right aligned or aligned with respect to the decimal point
5. The textual subscripts should be upright

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\date{10 dicembre 2015}

 \maketitle

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lsS[table-format=3.4]}
\toprule
Length target area              & mm   & 220 \\
Width target area               & mm   & 120 \\
Length upper surface            & mm   & 230 \\
Width lower surface             & mm   & 180 \\
Length inconel foil             & mm   & 250 \\
Width inconel foil              & mm   & 125 \\
Conductivity inconel            & W/mK &  14.8 \\
Conductivity duct tape          & W/mK &   0.2 \\
Conductivity steel              & W/mK &  51.9 \\
Thickness inconel               & mm   &   0.0254 \\
Thickness duct tape             & mm   &   0.18 \\
Thickness steel                 & mm   &   0.3 \\
$\varepsilon_{\mathrm{steel}}$  &      &   0.3 \\
$\varepsilon_{\mathrm{int}}$    &      &   0.25 \\
$\varepsilon_{\mathrm{amb}}$    &      &   1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Dimensioni del banco}\label{tab:dimensioni_banco}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]